# How to use cardStyleInterpolator in react navigation 6 in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

According to the documention in version 6, we can use the cardStyleInterpolator like this

```
import { CardStyleInterpolators } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// ...

<Stack.Screen
  name="Profile"
  component={Profile}
  options={{
    title: 'Profile',
    cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forFadeFromBottomAndroid,
  }}
/>;
```

This means that we have to install @react-navigation/stack also? because this code is not working in react navigation 6. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes you have to install @react-navigation/stack  because, you're importing from it.